# Under which condition does "Browser" button as Debug target appear in Debug toolbar?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Sorry if my question is bit loose, I didn't know how to describe it any better.

I have an ASP.NET application in VS2017, and I played around with it.
After some playing around (I really don't know what exactely I did), the combobox that ususally says "Debug" and "Any CPU" or "x86" suddenly said "Firefox" (which is my browser).

I could have started the project using my browser, I think.

No matter what I do now, this "Firefox" button doesn't appear in the Debug toolbar anymore.

Does anybody know under which conditions this button shows up?
And would clicking it be just the same as clicking the "Browser link dashboard" item in the Debug toolbar of VS2017?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button actually becomes visible when the web project is set as the start project.

One again I made the mistake of just selecting the project in the solution hierarchy, assuming that would "activate" the project.

But I had to set it as the "Start project".